# Remove numbers from beginning of strings in a numbered list with SQLite

Tags: sql, string, sqlite, trim

I have a long numbered list imported into a table, the strings are in the following format:

```
1. fdhsglahs sdhkgs
2. urgbvdgh ndovh
3. 8yhbnxjghr nvdfo dfhioj
...
9999. vnur neeu nu
```

I want to remove the numbers in the beginning of the string, the `"."` adjacent to the number, and any number of spaces that come immediately after the `"."` and before the next character (that is, before the beginning of the string itself).

Can't find a method to do that in SQLite.

Please notice, some of the strings contain numbers as part of the string, which are not to be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this requirement you can use [string functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html) like `substr()`, `instr()` and `ltrim()`:

```
select ltrim(substr(col, instr(col, '.') + 1))
from tablename
```

Replace `col` with the column's name.
this code returns the part of the string after the `.` left trimmed of spaces.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/h3SfTBxdf6gFY1HTamWL3b/2).

If you want to update the table:

```
update tablename
set col = ltrim(substr(col, instr(col, '.') + 1));
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/h3SfTBxdf6gFY1HTamWL3b/4).